# How to store data in android localstorage using JS

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm using `localStorage.setItem()` for setting the data in the localstorage of my browser
but I don't know what is happening in my android browser the data is not getting saved in localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem("mytime", Date.now());
```

Comment: What are you using to determine that "the data is not getting saved?"

Comment: @daddygames Actually I'm making a typeform where i'm saving the data ontype to the localstorage i'm checking that whatever data that i saved from the android browser textarea is not getting saved

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. The mobile browser also has localStorage & sessionStorage. Check [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Refer [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/?search=localstorage) too...

If your data is not getting stored in localStorage of mobile devices. You could debug mobile devices by

- Android -[remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/).
- iOS - [remote web inspector](https://moduscreate.com/blog/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)

Comment: I'm using the chrome inspect actually from chrome inspect the data is getting stored but from mobile when i'm typing on the mobile then it is not gettting saved

Comment: can you inspect using remote web inspector in your mobile chrome and check the values. If there are any error message, update the question.

Comment: Oh...! I'm sorry actually there is nothing error is coming okay let me create a new sandbox there i'll provide you the detail